# Closest point in set describing positive polynomial over finite interval

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $T\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$ and $x=\{a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{N}\}\in X$ be a random set of coefficients, such that $p(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}t^{n}$ is a polynomial on finite interval $[0,T]$.
Let $Y\subset X$, such that $\forall\{b_{1},b_{2},...,b_{N}\}=y\in Y\land t\in[0,T]:p(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}t^{n}\geq0$. Finally, I would like to find $$\text{argmin}_{y}||y-x||^{2}_{2}$$
Or in other words, is there a way to find the closest set of coefficients, such that a finite polynomial is nonnegative over a finite interval given a random set of coefficients?

Comment: By $\|p\|_2^2$, do you mean $\int_0^T p^2(t)\,dt$ or something else? But in any case, the answer to your question as asked is no. The set $Y$ you chose is open. As a result, if $x \notin Y$, then for any $y \in Y$, there will be some $y' \in Y$ that is a little closer to $x$. If you had defined $Y$ as $$Y = \{p \in X\mid p(t) \ge 0 \forall t \in [0,T]\}$$ instead of demanding $> 0$, then there would be solutions (though there may be more than one $y$ minimizing the distance to $x$, which still makes the argmin problematic).

Comment: No, in words it is: "the closest finite set of polynomial coefficients $y$ with $p_{y}(t)$ nonnegative over $[0,T]$, to any random finite set of polynomial coefficients $x$, thus $\text{argmin}||y-x||^{2}_{2}$". The set should be closed, it is a numerical problem, not analytical. So, how would yo have any idea of the shape of this set? I feel it is limited by Abel's law.

Comment: Who do you think you are fooling??? We can all see you just edited your question to fix the particular issue that I pointed out. To pretend that was what you asked in the first place is very poor behavior.

Comment: That's why I said: "the set should be closed" and meant that this open/closed set characteristic, is not really the issue. The actual shape is.